# Open browsers on remote machines using SSH

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, ssh, browser

I have connected two Windows machines (Example Machine A and Machine B) using SSH via Cygwin.

Steps I have checked so far:

1. when I try log-in without the password - it works.
2. I am trying to run Python code located in machine B from Machine A, it works. (it executes Python)
3. In the python code, I am using chromebroswer to launch and do some automation stuff. Code executes without any error.

**Expect the code should run chrome browser. But it is not opening the browser.**

Python Code:

````
browser=webdriver.Chrome("C:\Python\Python38-32\Projects\chromedriver.exe");
print('hello');
print('browser');
browser.get('https://www.google.com')
print('opened');```
````

Comment: are you sure the browser is installed in the same location in machine B as it is in machine A?

Comment: Could you please elaborate what you mean by two windows machines connected using SSH? As SSH rather alien to Windows OS, the tools or their configuration may be the reason/contribution to a problem.

Comment: On which machine do you expect the browser to be opened? Machine A (I don't think it would work with the selected toolkit) or Machine B (maybe it would be possible, but I am not sure)

Comment: You should use double backslashes or better use slashes for you path. `"C:\\Python\\..."` or `C:/Python/.."`

Comment: Can you share the error log or the execution logs of your program? That can help. 
PS. It is better to do error handling in code.

Comment: @rvbarreto Yes the browser driver is installed on the same location.

Comment: @AlexanderPushkarev I want to run some automation script on client machines using password less way. so,i used SSH agent and server concept. In client machine i have installed cygwin. Other commands like creating folder installing software are working. But opening the browser is the problem.

from the example code i given the code executes till printing 'opened'. But the browser is not opened.

Comment: @MuthuKumar I might be mistaken, but my understanding is that cygwin and ssh would not allow you opening browser. I would consider using Selenium Grid (https://www.browserstack.com/guide/selenium-grid-tutorial). This probably should allow you to achieve something close to what you want.

Comment: @AlexanderPushkarev I some how  managed my requirement using selenium grid. thanks for the clue.

Comment: @MathuKumar Good! I will add this as an answer then